# Is FFmpegAudioDecoder supposed to reinitialize upon append of new init segment

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ffmpeg, video-streaming, html5-video

I am attempting to switch audio tracks but when switching the FFmpegAudioDecoder never reinitializes like it does with video tracks of differing resolutions. I am not certain if this is the intended behavior of FFmpegAudioDecoder and would love to learn more about the expected behavior.

When switching audio tracks I end up calling the following operations:

```
if sourceBuffer.getIsUpdate() {sourceBuffer.abort()}
sourceBuffer.remove(0-videoDuration)
initSegmentDataStream = fetch init segment of new audio representation
sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(initSegmentDataStream)
```

These are the Media tab messages from initial video load

```
ChunkDemuxer
Selected FFmpegAudioDecoder for audio decoding, config: codec: aac, profile: unknown, bytes_per_channel: 2, channel_layout: STEREO, channels: 2, samples_per_second: 48000, sample_format: Signed 16-bit, bytes_per_frame: 4, seek_preroll: 0us, codec_delay: 0, has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, discard decoder delay: false, target_output_channel_layout: STEREO, target_output_sample_format: Unknown sample format, has aac extra data: true
Cannot select DecryptingVideoDecoder for video decoding
Cannot select VDAVideoDecoder for video decoding
Cannot select VpxVideoDecoder for video decoding
Selected Dav1dVideoDecoder for video decoding, config: codec: av1, profile: av1 profile main, level: not available, alpha_mode: is_opaque, coded size: [1280,720], visible rect: [0,0,1280,720], natural size: [1280,720], has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, rotation: 0°, flipped: 0, color space: {primaries:BT709, transfer:BT709, matrix:BT709, range:LIMITED}
Dropping audio frame (DTS 0us PTS -105375us,-62709us) that is outside append window [0us,9223372036854775807us).
Dropping audio frame (DTS 42666us PTS -62708us,-20042us) that is outside append window [0us,9223372036854775807us).
Truncating audio buffer which overlaps append window start. PTS -20041us frame_end_timestamp 22625us append_window_start 0us
Effective playback rate changed from 0 to 1
```

For comparison this is what I get when appending the init segment of a different video resolution / track

```
video decoder config changed midstream, new config: codec: av1, profile: av1 profile main, level: not available, alpha_mode: is_opaque, coded size: [1920,1080], visible rect: [0,0,1920,1080], natural size: [1920,1080], has extra data: false, encryption scheme: Unencrypted, rotation: 0°, flipped: 0, color space: {primaries:BT709, transfer:BT709, matrix:BT709, range:LIMITED}
```

Chrome version: Version 119.0.6045.123 (Official Build)

When appending the new init segment of an audio track I was expecting the FFmpegAudioDecoder to be reinitialized like the Dav1dVideoDecoder does for video tracks